# error on Dadhi and Debian 11

Tags: debian

I have this error if I want to use dahdi_echocan_oslec

```
modprobe dahdi_echocan_oslec 

[ 3322.067588] dahdi_echocan_oslec: Unknown symbol oslec_create (err -2)
[ 3322.067634] dahdi_echocan_oslec: Unknown symbol oslec_update (err -2)
[ 3322.067706] dahdi_echocan_oslec: Unknown symbol oslec_free (err -2)
```

very strange that Debian release a driver with this bug.

I try to compile now a new kernel..maybe..

Comment: I think the bug is with dahdi-linux, not Debian

Comment: yes, is with dahdi-linux, I recompile the kernel and I get same error

Comment: Have you checked the git repo for issues?

Comment: which git repo?

Comment: dahdi-linux since that's the module that doesn't compile ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found.
I recompile the package but instead of their "echo" dir I use the echo dir of kernel sources

```
sudo cp -av /usr/src/linux-5.15.80/drivers/misc/echo/ drivers/staging/echo
```

I made this on a Slackware, but I think after recompile the kernel will work also on Debian

```
modprobe dahdi_echocan_oslec
[ 1818.809095] dahdi_echocan_oslec: Registered echo canceler 'OSLEC'
```